# can Azure AD B2C federate to a SAML based IDP?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I mean azure ad b2c as Service Provider and non-microsoft SAML Based IDP as an identity provider.

I want to use non-microsoft SAML based IDP to federate with azure ad b2c application which is going to be service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see this link as an example of how to federate with any SAML idp:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-salesforce-custom?tabs=applications